# Proof verification: The Cohen algebra of Borel modulo meagre sets is complete.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, boolean-algebra, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

I asked this a while back and got no replies. I think I have a proof now but I'm a bit suspicious of how easy it is (or perhaps I was overthinking it from the start). In any case, I would appreciate some verification.

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the Borel algebra of borel mod meagre sets in $\omega^\omega$ (i.e, $A \sim B$ if $A \Delta B$ is meagre where $A, B$ are Borel). I want to show this is complete, i.e, every subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{B}$ has a unique upper bound $\sum A$. Let $[B] \in \mathbb{B}$ denote the equivalence class of the Borel set $B$ with respect to the equiv relation above.

First, $\mathbb{B}$ has a countable dense set: $\{ [N_s] : s \in \omega^{<\omega}\}$. From this one can conclude that $\mathbb{B}$ has the ccc- this follows from countable dense subset fairly easily.

Now suppose $[B_\alpha]_{\alpha < \mu}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{B}$. To show completeness we show that $\sum [B_\alpha]$ exists.

If $\mu \leq \omega_1$, let $A_\alpha = B_\alpha\setminus \cup_{\beta < \alpha} B_\beta$ be the disjointifications. Then by ccc there must be some $\gamma < \omega_1$ such that $[A_\alpha] = [\emptyset]$ for all $\alpha > \gamma$ (since the $[A_\alpha]$ form an antichain). Then simply see that $\sum_{\alpha < \mu}[B_\alpha] = \sum_{\alpha < \mu}[A_\alpha] = \sum_{\alpha < \gamma}[A_\alpha]$ and the last one exists due to ccc.

Next inductively assume we have this for all cardinals below $\mu$. And given $\{[B_\alpha]\}_{\alpha < \mu}$, by inductive hypothesis $[A_\alpha]  = \sum_{\beta < \alpha}[B_\alpha]$ exists for all $\alpha < \mu$. *Then* I think I can just define $[C_\alpha] = [B_\alpha] - [A_\alpha]$.

Notice that here if $\alpha < \beta$ and $[A_\alpha] < [A_\beta]$ (i.e, $[A_\alpha] \neq [A_\beta]$). Then we would have that $[C_\alpha] \perp [C_\beta] $ as well. In order to keep $\{[C_\alpha] : \alpha < \mu\}$ from being an uncountable antichain then we must then have that the $[A_\alpha]$ only take on countably many different values. This means that $\sum_{\alpha < \mu}[A_\alpha]$ exists and $\sum_{\alpha < \mu} [B_\alpha] = \sum_{\alpha < \mu}[A_\alpha]$.

Does this seem correct? I was pretty cavalier about using ccc and when antichains are formed so I wanted some confirmation. Hopefully I am not making this out to be far tougher than it is.

Comment: I think a ccc $\sigma$-complete BA modulo a $\sigma$-ideal is always complete. Isn't this what your proof shows? It also applies to the Borel sets modulo the null sets (for Lebesgue measure), and these complete BA's are known to be non-isomorphic.

Comment: I think the proof generalizes, yes. Do the steps look correct?

Comment: Also "Meager" is also an accepted spelling (referring to your edits): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set